# is there a possibility to create a custom command for the Kendo UI Grid for Angular2?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

The KendoUI Grid for Angular2 supports the following commands out of the box:

- kendoGridAddCommand
- kendoGridCancelCommand
- kendoGridEditCommand
- kendoGridRemoveCommand
- kendoGridSaveCommand

For my current project I need to implement a customCommand. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by custom command? You can simply add a button inside command column template and hook a click handler to it. Isn't this what you need?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i need. but the click event doesn't give me the row context of where I clicked. 
in this example there are predefined comands that take care of the context and what button was clicked ecactly: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

i just need custom comands in order to be able to add custom buttons with different calls than the predefined ones .

Comment: found already a solution by using the **kendoGridCellTemplate**  

`<template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
<button (click)="sortAsc(dataItem)">asc</button>
        <button (click)="sortDesc(dataItem)">desc</button>
      </template>`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="myData">
    <!-- Columns -->
    <kendo-grid-column field="id" title="ID"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name"> </kendo-grid-column>
    <!-- Commands -->
    <kendo-grid-command-column title="Commands">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <button kendoButton icon="calendar" (click)="myCustomAction(dataItem)">
                My Custom Button
            </button>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-command-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**TypeScript**

```
public myCustomAction(dataItem: any) {
    // ...
}
```

Kendo Button Icons can be found [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/icons/icon/icon-list/).